# Where is this strange og:description coming from?

Tags: plugins, facebook

I noticed in my home page's source code:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="This is an example page. It's different
from a blog post because it will stay in one place and will show up in your site 
navigation (in most themes). Most people start with an About page that introduces
them to potential site visitors. It might say s" />
```

This is a problem since this is what Facebook uses when I post the main URL of my site to a Facebook wall... so it just looks stupid.

I can't find that string anywhere in my WP admin settings, or in the "Facebook Open Graph Options" setting (as part of the "Facebook OpenGraph" plugin that I have installed). It's also not in any of my theme's template files, and it's not on my actual about page.

Where can I find this description, so I can change it?!

Thank you-- E

Comment: Plugin support is not really the aim of this forum [see FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq). That said, I believe that particular plugin duplicates the `description` meta tag, which WP generates by default. However without a link to your site it's hard to be much help.

Comment: Sounds like you should try different plugin, or contact the author of the plugin

Comment: I agree. But it also seems like that plugin is pulling that copy ("This is an example page. It's different from a blog post because...") from *somewhere,* which is what I'm trying to figure out. Could the plugin be hiding the field where that copy appears, which is why I can't find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a FaceBook plugin most likely using the output of the `post excerpt` - via `get_the_excerpt()` or whatever - to populate the `og:description` meta tag.

It's placed there automatically by the plugin.

Comment: Thank you-- I think you're right. My problem is, I can't figure out exactly where it's getting that excerpt from. I.e. I'm looking at all my posts and pages and that copy doesn't seem to appear in any fields anywhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: The excerpt is automatically taken from the content of a post. A shortened version of it. The text you mentioned above is the text used for the default page created when you install WordPress. Look for that first page. It should have the title "About" I think

Comment: You mentioned that this description text shows up in the homepage. What does your homepage look like? Is it a list of blog posts? or a static page?

Answer (score 1):

That's the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/).

Comment: Right. But where is that string in the admin tool? I'm looking at all my posts and pages and that copy ("This is an example page. It's different from a blog post because...") doesn't seem to appear in any fields anywhere.

Comment: Nowhere. It's in a plugin or a theme.

Answer (score 0):

that looks like the text from the sample page that all WordPress installs come with. Have you checked there?

Comment: Yes, but I can't see that sample page anywhere in my site, and I can't figure out why it would be pulling that into the og:description (since it doesn't appear in any of my templates).

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The plugin was pulling it from the body copy of a strange page that I wasn't using. That page was all custom HTML, so that body copy was never displayed on the site.

The moral of the story: check everything, everywhere, if you see weird copy... odds are it's in some field buried deep below a tab or two...

Answer (score 0):

I found the text and changed it directly from the database (PHPmyadmin), in the table "wp_posts", in the field ID 2, column "post_content". I hope it helps !